# How to play audio files in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Pretty new to xcode and need some help. I want to play audio files one after each other.

Let's say I have these files with the audio:

audio1 = "Hello", audio2 = "how", audio3 = "are", audio4 = "you"

...and when I press the "Play sound" button it should read out "Hello How are you".

Can anyone help me out with this? I have googled this a lot, but there is no easy example for this matter... for newbies ;)

Comment: Are you trying to use voice synthesizer (text to speech) or simply want to play audio files simultaneously?

Comment: I usually use iTunes to play audio. Xcode is just an IDE.

Comment: @Desdenova: I want to play audio files simultaneously... or after each other that is.

Comment: @Abizern: I guess you are trying to be funny. You're not.

Comment: @trojanfoe: It would be nice if you actually read my question before you throw the duplicate card. Quote: "I want to play audio files". My reputation drops like a rock when you do what you do. Please don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AVQueuePlayer's method

```
+ (AVQueuePlayer *)queuePlayerWithItems:(NSArray *)items
```

and you can refer to this question

[iOS xcode4 AVQueuePlayer not playing sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160774/ios-xcode4-avqueueplayer-not-playing-sound)

Comment: Yes, this might be something I can use. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.